# Permission Denied when executing liquibase command in Jenkins

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, liquibase

I'm getting this `permission denied` error when I'm trying to execute a liquibase command as a shell command.

[image]

```
/tmp/jenkins976.sh: line 3: /home/ec2-user/liquibase/liquibase: Permission denied
```

I've given the necessary permissions to the liquibase executable.

[image]

This worked fine with a previous version of jenkins and started getting this error after upgrading jenkins.

- Current Jenkins version: 2.168

Appreciate any help to resolve this issue.

Comment: I would add a call to `whoami` in your shell script before calling liquibase just to ensure it is running with the correct user.

Comment: @SteveDonie Its the jenkins user and i've given execution permission for that user.